# Why Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG does not seem to work when drawing at same place on Canvas?

Tags: android, canvas, antialiasing

There is an issue with anti-alias when trying to draw multiple times at same place using the android `Canvas`.

First I'm initializing `paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG)` and then setting stroke cap to `Paint.Cap.ROUND`.

Then, if I call `canvas.drawPoint(x, y, paint)` once causes the following result:

[image]

While calling `canvas.drawPoint(x, y, paint)` multiple times (100 in this example) causes this:

[image]

I've created an example with minimal code to run this on GitHub: [android-canvas-antialias](https://github.com/tatorodrigo/android-canvas-antialias)

I noticed if I draw the points with a certain distance, the anti-alias seems to work as expected (first image). But drawing it with little offset causes the same anti-alias issue (second image).

Is there any setup that need to be done for this to work while drawing the points at same place? Or I simply may not be drawing at same place (or with very little offset)?

EDIT: the real issue is because I'm trying to draw a width variable line segment. See the `MainActivity.drawSegment` on git repository.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think this is a problem, I mean, a bug itself. And even if solvable trivially I guess.

The pixels of the edge of the circle are draw with some alpha, e.g. a red pixel with 25% alpha if you overlay it with more 3 pixels with same alpha you will get a 100% red pixel.

A workaround would be manage all shapes created and check if some of them has the same size + position (maybe color too) and just draw one of them.

The link below explain how the Antialiasing works, might help.

http://web.cs.wpi.edu/~matt/courses/cs563/talks/antialiasing/methods.html

Answer (score 4):

It works correctly. Anti-aliasing is when the edges of the shape are semi-transparent. When you multiply the shapes, the semi-transparent pixels become not transparent and you get "ragged" edges.

The solution is not to do this.